# Using bolt-js , can one slack app post messages as multiple users?

Tags: authorization, bots, slack, slack-api, bolt

I'm making slack app like this:

1. open modal by slash command
2. Input text to textarea on modal
3. Push submit button
4. Text is translated by Google API and posted to channel

On step 4, I'd like to post translated text as user (not as bot) .
In additon, if other member post a translated text, bot will post  the text  as the user.

By using bolt-js, Can I make app like this ?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use boltJS...there are a lot of restrictions on this. You can do a lot of this functionality with Slack's Workflow Builder functionality in a 'bolt' shortcut menu in the messaging section. Fumbled around with BoltJS, great for a simple stuff. I recommend for development:
https://github.com/slackapi/node-slack-sdk  > examples file
But for something like that functionality described above: https://slack.com/slack-tips/workflow-builder-examples   >

I would personally use slash command for retrieving data from an outside source, and I would 1.) use a workflow builder example that will be setup within the shortcuts menu, for users to submit a form(Channel #1 == #formSubmitChannel) that then post to ANOTHER channel for where I would want to listen for this data to submit to.

2.) You can have a slack app within this channel(Channel #2 == #formDataRetrievalChannel) that has the 'event listener' functionality. BoltJS has this out of the box. But on event(posting of a keyword or message within that channel) of a user posting w/in this channel I would then grab those value and translate them with the Google API via within the Application prior to posting that data to the Slack Channel(Channel #2).

Just my 2 cents.